# How to get the year difference between two dates?

Tags: python, date

I'm developing a small program for an insurance company to see how old a person is (this changes the ranges of cover we can offer). I can easily calculate the different in the years but it does not take into account the days/months. I there any way of doing this without importing things from elsewhere?

Comment: Whats the format of your date? Is it some sort of Date object?

Comment: How are you currently calculating the difference in years?

Comment: It is the age of a client: DD/MM/YYYY. To calculate the difference in years I am subtracting the year of birth from 2016 as an integer.

Comment: Check out the `datetime` library.

Comment: Does that require me to import something to make it function correctly or can I just input the code and it'll work?

Comment: You need to import. Please check documentation: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

as you are working with python you **must** use the datetime module. Lets have a look.

```
from datetime import datetime

bday = '1978/11/21'
dt = datetime.strptime(bday, '%Y/%m/%d')
diff = datetime.now() - dt
diff.days
```

Gives you 13764

Comment: I got the following error: ImportError: no module named datetime on line 1

Comment: @RupertDavis Just say `import datetime` and then replace every instance of `datetime` with `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: @RupertDavis can you mark the issue as resolved please :)

Comment: Camille: How is 13764 the year difference between the two dates?

Comment: @martineau it is the diff in days

Comment: Camille: Yes...my point was because the OP asked for the _year_ difference, not the difference in days.